# Find E-Mails with an exact e-mail address on an IMAP server using PHP

Tags: php, email, search, imap

I want to connect to an IMAP-server and find all E-Mails that were sent to `abc@server.tld`. I tried:

```
$mbox = imap_open("{imap.server.tld/norsh}", "imap@server.tld", "5ecure3");
$result = imap_search($mbox, "TO \"abc@server.tld\"", SE_UID);
```

but this also listed e-Mails that were sent e.g. to `123abc@server.tld`. Is it somehow possible to do a search for exact matches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: you can't. I didn't find anything in [RFC 2060 - Internet Message Access Protocol - Version 4rev1](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2060.html) saying that it can be done.

But, there is a workaround. First fetch all emails that contain `abc@server.tld`, then iterate through the results and select only the exact matches.

```
$searchEmail = "abc@server.tld";
$emails = imap_search($mbox, "TO $searchEmail");
$exactMatches = array();

foreach ($emails as $email) {
    // get email headers
    $info = imap_headerinfo($mbox, $email);

    // fetch all emails in the TO: header
    $toAddresses = array();
    foreach ($info->to as $to) {
        $toAddresses[] = $to->mailbox . '@' . $to->host;
    }   

    // is there a match?
    if (in_array($searchEmail, $toAddresses)) {
        $exactMatches[] = $email;
    }
}
```

Now you have all emails matching `abc@server.tld` in `$exactMatches`

Comment: Great answer, this work around of course works for searching other fields, like `subject`, as well.